# PowerBI date hierarchy to match with existing date table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I have DirectQuery connection to SQL server. In this query I have Date table with values like `20200414` and `20200415` etc.

I want to use a slicer visualization to be able to pick between the last 7 days as a slider. When I make a slicer visualization and add my existing Date table the slicer only shows values as tickbox but I want a slider. I created a new date hierarchy and got the slider I needed but now I need to link it to my existing date table.

I do not have similar columns in my date hierarchy and date table.

Existing:

[image]

Date Hierarchy:

[image]

How can I create a similar working Date Hierarchy that has a column like in my existing table? So I could just manage relationships for them to work.

Code I use in my hierarchy:

```
let
    StartDate = #date(StartYear,1,1),
    EndDate = #date(EndYear,12,31),
    NumberOfDays = Duration.Days( EndDate - StartDate ),
    Dates = List.Dates(StartDate, NumberOfDays+1, #duration(1,0,0,0)),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Dates, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Converted to Table",{{"Column1", "FullDateAlternateKey"}}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Renamed Columns",{{"FullDateAlternateKey", type date}}),
    #"Inserted Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Year", each Date.Year([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Year", "Month", each Date.Month([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Month Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month", "Month Name", each Date.MonthName([FullDateAlternateKey]), type text),
    #"Inserted Quarter" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Month Name", "Quarter", each Date.QuarterOfYear([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Week of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Quarter", "Week of Year", each Date.WeekOfYear([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Week of Month" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Week of Year", "Week of Month", each Date.WeekOfMonth([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Day" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Week of Month", "Day", each Date.Day([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Day of Week" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day", "Day of Week", each Date.DayOfWeek([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Day of Year" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day of Week", "Day of Year", each Date.DayOfYear([FullDateAlternateKey]), type number),
    #"Inserted Day Name" = Table.AddColumn(#"Inserted Day of Year", "Day Name", each Date.DayOfWeekName([FullDateAlternateKey]), type text)
in
    #"Inserted Day Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is duplicate the column SalesDate in the Query Editor and then change the data type of your new column to Date. The result should be like this
[image]

Then you can easily connect both of your tables.

Comment: This table is connected with DirectQuery and updates everyday. If I add this new column manually doesn't this mean that I have to add a new line to the newly created column manually also or can I make it update according to SalesDate column?